# Set default values for missing properties in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume a component receives a nested property in React from its parent :

```
getDefaultProps: function(){
    return ({
        "data" : {
            "style": {
                pieChart: true, // otherwise it'd be a donut chart
                radius: 100
            },
            "series": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    });
},
```

It's possible to receive a property with some missing values (e.g we may receive series but not style , or we may receive a value for radius but not for pieChart)

How can we define default values only for the missing values ? and keep the rest of values as they are received

Answer (score 2):

you can't set the default values for deep objects in the `getDefaultProps` method but you can inside the `componentWillMount` method.

```
React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      "data" : {
        "style": {
          pieChart: true, // otherwise it'd be a donut chart
          radius: 100
        },
        "series": {
          "data": []
        }
      }
    }
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    if(!this.props.data.style) {
      this.props.data.style = {
        pieChart: true,
        radius: 100
      };
    }
    if(!this.props.data.series) {
      this.props.data.series = {
        data: []
      };
    }
  }
});
```

however this is not recommended as React best practices state that you shouldn't modify `this.props` from within the component. What you really should do is use the logic in `componentWillMount` to format the object to your liking before you pass it into the component.

Answer (score 0):

Props are meant to be overwritten. You can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` function to handle any negotiation between the old props and the new props, but you will have to write out the logic yourself. Not totally sure of what you're data structure looks like, but I'm sure you could do the job with underscore's `_.extend` and `_.defaults`.

Comment: The problem is "componentWillReceiveProps" is not called for the initial render .

Comment: will you have variable data even for the initial render? if not, getDefaultProps will do the job then, and componentWillReceiveProps will do the job subsequently. if the data is variable, you can simply transform props in the render method. 


duplicating logic like that is fairly common, IMO. In my company's flux stack, we often do similar and sometimes identical things for getInitialState and for when the store changes.